# Taylor series for Sine calculation

Tags: python-3.x

I've challenged myself to code a function which returns the sine of a given angle.
But I do not want to import any modules at all, I just want to do this with the normal Python 3.

I tried out many different solutions, and tested my function to determine the factorial of a number. This function works perfectly, so the problem has to be somewhere else.

```py
def fakult(n):

    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError

    if n == 0:
        return 1

    else:
        fak = 1
        for i in range(2,n+1):
            fak *= i
        print(fak)
        return fak

def sin(x, attempts=10):
    a=0
    for n in range(attempts):
        #"fakult" calls a function which return the factorial of the term in the parantheses
        a+=((-1) ** n) * ((x ** ((2 * n) + 1)) / (fakult(2 * n + 1)))

    return a
```

The rest of my code is without mistakes, nor are there any error messages. The result is just completely wrong. I made some basic debugging, and put some print commands between the lines..
The sine of 90 degrees should be 0,89....
The function returns -1.0651331796981347e+20

Comment: Do you mean sine? not sinus? and what do you mean by faculty?

Comment: either initialize `a = 0` or start the range from 1 `for n in range(1, attempts)`. You are initializing `a` to `x` and then adding `x` again in the first iteration when `n = 0`. This still don't explain the astronomical number but it's a start

Comment: we will need to see the implementation of `fakult` as the problem might be there... (this is not a reproducible code...). Also, try to do some basic debugging, for example adding a print at the end of each iteration and see that the results match what you expect

Comment: jep i meant sine... and faculty means XY! (e.g. 5! = 1*2*3*4*5)

Comment: Are you working in degrees or radians?  Wouldn't the Taylor series only be useful for the range -pi<x<pi which means 90 (or 28.6 pi) is quite far out of the useful range for this calculation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sine of a right angle, use radians:

```
import math

def fakult(n):

    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError

    if n == 0:
        return 1

    else:
        fak = 1
        for i in range(2,n+1):
            fak *= i
        # print(fak)
        return fak

def calc_sin(x, attempts=10):
    a=0
    for n in range(attempts):
        #"fakult" calls a function which return the factorial of the term in the parantheses
        a+=((-1) ** n) * ((x ** ((2 * n) + 1)) / (fakult(2 * n + 1)))

    return a

calc_sin(90*math.pi/180)
Out[1]: 1.0
```

or if you want the sine of 90 radians you need to remember that the taylor series is only valid for one cycle centered on 0:

```
val = 90*180/math.pi
val
Out[22]: 5156.620156177409

val_deg = (val)%360
val_deg
Out[24]: 116.62015617740872

val_deg_rad = val_deg*math.pi/180
val_deg_rad
Out[26]: 2.0354056994857865

calc_sin(val_deg_rad)
Out[27]: 0.8939966636005003
```